# Append #id to all css classes in C#

Tags: c#, css, class, append

i would be grateful if some of you please could help me with this.

Imagine I have this code in a .css file:

```
body {
color: white;
background-color: #aaaaaa }
header {
color: blue;
background-color: #bbbbbb }
main {
color: red;
background-color: #cccccc }
footer {
color: green;
background-color: #dddddd }
```

Now imagine i get that file in my C# code as a string and I want to add to every class on it an #id as below:

```
#someID body {
color: white;
background-color: #aaaaaa }
#someID header {
color: blue;
background-color: #bbbbbb }
#someID main {
color: red;
background-color: #cccccc }
#someID footer {
color: green;
background-color: #dddddd }
```

How can i achieve this?
I don't know if using a Regular Expression or if there is an easier way to achieve it (ex. some library to deal with .css's??).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest using LESS or SASS. C# isn't the best tool (most likely) for what you are trying to accomplish. With LESS you can simply import the import and wrap it in #someID. Then compiler would do the rest.

Comment: I was going to suggest less as a good tool too. http://www.dotlesscss.org/ is a .NET implementation. If this is literally the only time you want to do it though then it could be overkill...

Comment: Please check my solution, it works as per your expectations

Answer (score 0):

Just use the C# `Replace` method:

```
// Replace the body with "#someID body" and then replace 
// every closing brace with "} #someID"
string newCss = yourCss.Replace("body", "#someID body").Replace("}", "} #someID");

// Remove the last "#someID"
newCss = newCss.Substring(0, newCss.Length - 8);
```

[Proof that it works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2lbvMS)

Comment: and what about the existing element tag after the element with the ID someID ? the replacement here will make  body { } to be  body #someID { } instead of #someID body {}

Comment: Yes, I know that you are only replacing the opening brace, but this way the result will not be as what's expected; the order of body and #someID will be reversed.

Comment: There is \n present between #someId and name. Need some logic to replace \n to string.Empty. check mine it works as expected. I trimmed \n.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however i've got this problem now (this is the resulting code) seems like @ is causing some trouble, as it doesn't follow the rule: `#someID @charset "UTF-8";nav{position:relative;line-height:0;background-color:rgba(230,230,230,0.8);}#someID .navbar-fixed{z-index:7900}` and this too in the same css: `#someID @media only screen and (max-width:601px){nav{height:32px}#someID nav .hv_menu_home i{font-size:2rem}`

Answer (score 0):

I need to borrow the logic used by CodingYoshi but with making a small change:

```
string newCss = yourCss.Replace("}", "} #someID ");
```

Here I'am replacing the ending brace with another one plus `#someID`. But here we need to be careful not to replace the last ending brace in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about LINQ, but you can achieve this by applying following logic.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string[] splitedString = inputString.Split('}');
        foreach(string item in splitedString){
            string conString = "#SomeId " + item.Trim('\n') +'}';
            sb.Append(conString + "\n");

    }
```

Implementation: [DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S972Pr)